# wsgi:error - Module Not Found Error in Ubuntu - Flask App Hosting

Tags: python, apache, flask-sqlalchemy, ubuntu-16.04, mod-wsgi

I am hosting a flask app on ubuntu server I installed all the packages and my python file (**init**.py) is working correctly when I run it using `python3 __init__.py` but it gives me a `Internal Server Error` when I tried it to access using Public IP Address.

I installed all the modules properly. But I don't know why it is giving me error

> Module Not Found.

Here is the `error.log`

```
[Sun Feb 28 03:36:38.569432 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4692] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Feb 28 03:36:38.579915 2021] [core:notice] [pid 4692] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Feb 28 03:36:40.695140 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 4696] [client 157.34.94.187:50553] mod_wsgi (pid=4696): Target WSGI script '/var/www/dj/dj.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Feb 28 03:36:40.695209 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 4696] [client 157.34.94.187:50553] mod_wsgi (pid=4696): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/dj/dj.wsgi'.
[Sun Feb 28 03:36:40.695473 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 4696] [client 157.34.94.187:50553] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Feb 28 03:36:40.695503 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 4696] [client 157.34.94.187:50553]   File "/var/www/dj/dj.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
[Sun Feb 28 03:36:40.695508 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 4696] [client 157.34.94.187:50553]     from dj import app as application
[Sun Feb 28 03:36:40.695515 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 4696] [client 157.34.94.187:50553]   File "/var/www/dj/dj/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Feb 28 03:36:40.695519 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 4696] [client 157.34.94.187:50553]     from flask_login import login_required
[Sun Feb 28 03:36:40.695537 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 4696] [client 157.34.94.187:50553] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_login'
```

Here is my `wsgi` file

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/dj/")

from dj import app as application
application.secret_key = 'SECERET'
```

And here is my project structure -

```
--var
---www
----dj(folder)
-----dj(folder) , dj.wsgi
------- __init__.py, static...
```

Comment: hi, have u solved the problem? i am encountering the same problem and it's driving me crazy as i have spent 2 whole days on this.

Answer (score -1):

Does pip freeze return flask_login among installed packages?
Your log says that it can't find flask_login module.

Comment: Yes flask_login and all other modules are listed there.

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to the question. Please consider answering those questions which don't require a confirmation from the user until you reach a reputation of 50 and able to comment on posts.